# At a time show two different ads on same placement id in inmobi native ads

Tags: ios, iphone, inmobi

I want two or more different ads on same app + same placement id in inmobi Ads Manager in native ads. In a tableview and every two cells display ads but show different ads on same placement id.

[image]

Currently, same ads display, but I want different ads on same app and same placement id.